# expect() with no actual expectations

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

**The Problem:**

Recently, while reviewing our existing test codebase, I've noticed a dangerous kind of typo/mistake when `expect()` was used without the "matching" part:

```
expect(page.filters.fromDateLabel.getText(), "After");
```

I'm pretty sure `toEqual()` was meant to be used here:

```
expect(page.filters.fromDateLabel.getText()).toEqual("After");
```

The problem with this is that `jasmine` would not fail the expectation in this case (well, obviously because nothing was actually expected). And this gets us to a more serious problem - nothing was actually tested in a test case - it was passing with no expectations made. We were getting a false sense of what was tested.

**The Question:**

I want to catch these mistakes as fast as possible. How do you think I should handle the problem?

**Thoughts:**

- somehow fail a test case if there was no expectations made in it (not sure if `jasmine` has anything like this built-in)
- "patch" the `expect()` and issue a warning/raise an error if nothing was called on the "expect" part
- use static code analysis - define a custom [`eslint`](http://eslint.org/) rule

Comment: The lint rule would be my preference as it's the least invasive

Comment: @Phil I agree, this is what I'm thinking about to try first, since it sounds like the simplest option - + we have already a set of custom eslint rules defined. Generally speaking, I also like the option #1 - it probably makes sense to point the e2e developer that he/she hasn't actually checked anything in a test..thanks for the point!

Comment: @Phil and yeah, in an ideal world, things like this should not happen since a developer writing a test must see the test failing and make sure it checks what was supposed to be checked. But, typos and mistakes happen to everyone - I just want to have these things caught "fresh" :)

Comment: Regarding #2, it would be simpler to override `expect` to throw an error if `arguments.length > 1`

Comment: @Phil yup, made a custom ESLint rule (provided in the answer). Thanks for participation!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The custom ESLint rule provided in the answer is now a part of [`eslint-plugin-jasmine`](https://github.com/tlvince/eslint-plugin-jasmine) 1.6.0:

- [`valid-expect`](https://github.com/tlvince/eslint-plugin-jasmine/blob/master/docs/rules/valid-expect.md)

---

Old Answer:

Here is a [custom ESLint rule](http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules) I've ended up with:

```
module.exports = function (context) {
  return {
    // checking "expect()" arguments
    CallExpression: function (node) {
      if (node.callee.name === 'expect') {
        if (node.arguments.length > 1) {
          context.report(node, 'More than one argument passed to expect()')
        } else if (node.arguments.length === 0) {
          context.report(node, 'No arguments passed to expect()')
        }
      }
    },

    // nothing called on "expect()"
    'CallExpression:exit': function (node) {
      if (node.callee.name === 'expect' && node.parent.type === 'ExpressionStatement') {
        context.report(node, 'Nothing called on expect()')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It checks for 3 things:

- more than 1 argument passed to `expect()`
- no arguments are passed to `expect()`
- there was nothing called on `expect()`

Here are the sample invalid `expect()` usages it currently catches:

```
expect(page.filters.fromDateLabel.getText(), "After");
expect("After");
expect();
```

---

As for the option #1, there is actually a quite related and useful `ESLint` rule being already implemented and open-sourced by [`eslint-plugin-jasmine`]:

- [Enforce expectation (missing-expect)](https://github.com/tlvince/eslint-plugin-jasmine/blob/master/docs/rules/missing-expect.md)

Answer (score 1):

I tend to think that the static analysis route is best, but if you’re looking for a quick and dirty way, here’s some code that grabs the expectations returned by all calls to `expect` and creates a proxy that tracks whether any of the expectation’s properties were ever used:

```
var unusedExpectations = new Set();

var originalExpect = window.expect;  // Should be empty after every spec
var expect = function() {
  var rawExpectation = originalExpect.apply(this, arguments);
  unusedExpectations.add(rawExpectation);  // Assume unused until used

  // Traverse expectation and its prototypes, copying all properties to
  // our proxy object. (Note that this becomes much simpler if you have
  // ES6 Proxy in your environment.)

  var proxy = {}
  for(var proto = rawExpectation; proto; proto = proto.__proto__) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto).forEach(function(prop) {
      if(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proxy, prop))
        return;
      Object.defineProperty(
        proxy, prop, {
          get: function() {
            // Aha! Somebody used this expectation for _something_.
            unusedExpectations.delete(rawExpectation);
            return rawExpectation[prop];
          }
        }
      );
    });
  }
  return proxy;
}
```

Put that in a place where it hides Jasmine’s `expect` from your specs, and then:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  unusedExpectations.clear();
});
afterEach(function() {
  expect(unusedExpectations.size).toEqual(0);
});
```

Caveats:

1. Kind of evil.
2. Will not catch `expect(foo).toBeFalsy;` (missing parens).
3. Counts the use of *any* property, so won’t catch `expect(foo).toString()`.

Still, it works!

One could add code to inspect the stack trace and extract the location of the offending `expect()`, but I imagine flagging which spec has an unused `expect()` is sufficient.

Comment: That's an interesting evil idea! :) I'll certainly try it out in practice! I've also posted solutions to option #1 and #3 - I guess we have sort of a complete picture here now with all of the different approaches. Thanks!